Trump’s use of the term deportation
Trump promises "to launch the largest deportation operation" in history? You Tube - CBS News
There is a debate currently in Italy on the use of the term “deportation” by Trump in a recent speech referring to illegal immigrants.
In some parts of Europe the term “deportation” is closely associated with the deportations of Jews during WWII to Nazi concentration camps. So the use of the term has been very badly received.
I guess that “deportation” has less historical and political connotations in the USA. Am I right?  or is Trump using such a strong term deliberately to convey a muscular but outrageous image to his electorate?

Worth noting that Nazis deliberately misused the term: they pretended to resettle Jews, in order to avoid those resisting, and to avoid local population from protesting. In elaborated ruse the Jews were asked to take with them documents, clothes, provisions and other necessities for supposedly settling in a new place. As for the local population - however widespread might have been the dislike of Jews in the Nazi-controlled territories, wishing them dead or even deliberately collaborating was not the majority sentiment - at least the Nazis were not sure about it.

You might as well say we can't use the words "solution" or "extermination" in English due to potential negative connotations from Naziism.  Words don't usually get tainted beyond use in this way.

I think a voting community which dislikes campaigning and provocative communication, even if it is coming from their own side, would be highly useful on the long term.

"Deportation" is a legal term of art in US immigration law.
There is a federal statutory provision for "orders of deportation."  The term deportation is also used by US federal agencies to describe the process of removing someone from the country, see for example usa.gov and ice.gov.  So it is a normal term to use to describe the legal processes for removing a person from the US.
The term "deportation" is also used as the question suggests in reference to the Holocaust, for example from the US Holocaust Memorial Museum (italics added).  However, at least in my experience the term does not have that connotation absent context.

Physical Displacement. Perpetrators used forced emigration, resettlement, expulsion, deportation, and ghettoization to physically displace Jewish individuals and communities.


The World War II context was forcibly removing people (or imprisoning them) on the basis of their lineage alone (i.e. Germany and non-aryan races). The term in America used currently almost always refers to taking people who have no legal right to be in the US and sending them back to their country of origin.
That is consistent with what Trump says in a recent interview For the sake of brevity, I have cherry picked parts to form a concise view. The full quotes ramble at length (as is Trump's wont).

We will be using local law enforcement. And we will absolutely start with the criminals that are coming in.


It would [involve using the military]. When we talk military, generally speaking, I talk National Guard.


But if I thought things were getting out of control, I would have no problem using the military, per se. We have to have safety in our country. We have to have law and order in our country. And whichever gets us there, but I think the National Guard will do the job.


We wouldn't have to [build new migrant detention camps]. Because we'll be bringing them out of the country. We're not leaving them in the country. We're bringing them out. It’s been done before.


But there wouldn't be that much of a need for [migrant detention camps], because of the fact that we're going to be moving them out. We're going to bring them back from where they came.


"on the basis of their lineage alone" not only. Homosexuals were also deported. Intellectuals and generally "opponents of the regime" as well.

@njzk2 Yes, but that was never within the scope of modern usage. Any American president who tried to do that would face a major backlash

I think that this question is based on a misconception. The word "deportation" is not loaded in this way in English, it's not a question of European vs. American.
It's certainly true that the equivalent word is loaded in German, which is why the AfD reacted to their plans being described as "deportation" and insisted that their "Remigration" plan shouldn't be called that (link in German), but the closest UK party to the AfD, Reform has the phrase "Immediate Deportation for Foreign Criminals" as one of their headline immigration policies in their manifesto. Nor is it only the extreme parties using this language, the Conservatives manifesto boasts of having "deported over 18,000 foreign national offenders".
Deportation in English is simply the process of removing people who do not have a right to be in the country. Whilst the politics around such removals is certainly fraught, the word itself does not carry the baggage stated in the question. Comments from other posters suggest that this is also true in many other European languages, but I can only comment on those I understand to a decent degree.

The term 'deportation' means the identification, detention, and removal of non-citizens from a nation (as opposed to the removal goods or objects, which is covered by the term 'exportation'). Every country has a procedure for deporting people, and most Western nations have established legal processes to determine who should and should not be subject to deportation. Historically, the US has had loose rules for immigration, particularly for those who enter the country for labor rather than seeking a citizenship path, but Trumpism (like nationalist movements generally) is expressly anti-immigrant, and so an increase in deportation-language is probably to be expected.
The problem with Trump's speech isn't the term 'deportation' per se, but with the explicit ideation of large-scale indiscriminate deportation. This is what begins to stir up images of people crammed into railroad cattle-cars and shipped to concentration camps for 'processing' and 'relocation'. Mass deportation of this sort — as the Nazis discovered trying to move Jews, Gypsies, and Communists, and the Ottomans discovered trying to relocate Armenians — is extremely cost-inefficient. People being relocated cannot produce anything of value, but must be housed, fed, clothed, provided medical care, guarded, and constrained until the moment they are sent from the territory, assuming the state can fond a foreign nation willing to repatriate them. The more people being deported, the greater the cost, and the greater the difficulties with repatriation. This invariably leads to cost-cutting and cost-recovery efforts, such as limitations on or rationing of food, shelter, water, and other necessities, sub-par medical care, overcrowding, or even the expropriation of any wealth the deported people might have or the implementation of forced labor to cover costs. In turn, these measure, lead to increases in disease, exposure, malnutrition, exhaustion, and violence in both detainees and overworked guards. Mass deportation efforts invariably carry a significant death toll, whether or not the deporting administration has any specific plan for inflicting death. The general fear is that if Trump implements this plan he will (wittingly or not) stumble his way into something like a genocide.
Argue the legalities of it anyway you like; if it happens it will be ugly.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

"The term 'deportation' literally means the identification, detention, and removal of non-citizens from a nation." source? I've found several definition, non of which correspond literally to yours.

@njzk2: I'm sorry that people are confused that I used the word 'literally' in the informal, emphatic sense (indicating a strong assertion), not in the translational sense (implying some exact word usage). The word 'deportation' is typically used in the sense presented in social, political, and legal discussion, and is rarely if ever used in other contexts. When we talk about sending away objects or things we usually use the word 'exportation'; deportation is restricted to sending away people. I didn't think there would be any confusion here, but I will think about revising the word.

For example, go to travel stack and search for "deportation"; the term is widely used there in a narrowly legalistic manner.  https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=deportation

Yeah, "deportation" is an fairly routine affair...

Deportation is the process of removing a noncitizen from the U.S. for violating immigration law.

... but also the name of a crime under the Nuremberg Tribunal statutes and thereafter. It all depends on the context. The latter is sometimes prefixed with "the crime of", to make the distinction more clear. About the latter, the UN e.g. says:

What are the crimes of deportation and forcible transfer?
Forcing people, by expulsion or other coercive acts, to leave a place where they are living lawfully for reasons not allowed by international law could be a crime against humanity, a war crime or both.
When people are displaced across an international border, it is called deportation. [...]

Emphasis on "living lawfully" mine.
It's not different than other context-dependent legal issues. Shooting someone can be self-dense. Or can be murder.

Surprisingly then by that definition, the deportations to concentration camps do not even count as "crime of deportation" because of course they had  a law for it!? It wasn't even deportation when no international border was crossed.

@HagenvonEitzen yep it wasn’t the crime of deportation, it was the crime of imprisonment, torture and death penalty under false charges. I don’t see a contradiction. You don’t need to be guilty of every single crime all at once, you can be guilty of just one or two at a time.

@HagenvonEitzen: well, that is indeed a point that is sometimes discussed. It's well known IMHO that the Nuremberg tribunal statutes declared ex-post-facto, if you like, that many Nazi laws were not in fact legal... according to higher standards of international law. (IIRC the very place was chose in part because the Nazi racial laws bore the same name.)

@JonathanReez: deportation was explicitly mentioned as a crime in the Nuremberg Tribunal statutes [Principle VI b]: "deportation to slave labor or for any other purpose of civilian population of or in occupied territory" and also [at VI c]: "Murder, extermination, enslavement, deportation and other inhumane acts done against any civilian population". You can argue that it was unnecessarily/redundantly so, but it was explicitly included.

Did it really apply to Jews living in (say) Berlin as of 1939 if they were moved to Sachsenhausen concentration camp rather than sent abroad? Obviously lots of other crimes did apply there but that specific case would not involve "deportation".

@JonathanReez: you should ask that  on H.SE, but I think the answer is 'yes'. The distinction that e.g. the UN makes now between deportation and "forcible transfer", with the latter applying inside borders and the former over borders wasn't considered at the time of the Nuremberg trials, AFAICR.

@JonathanReez Yes if you are taken from your place of residence and brought far away that is deportation (being brought away), whether that is a Gulag, an interment camp, a concentration camp or another country. Might need to look up the overlap with being exiled.

Nazi Germany did more than just the holocaust. The "deportations" probably are not referring to the death camps, but the bulk transfers of ethnic groups (Jews and other ethnic groups) out of the places where they had been living for years or even generations. Germany tried to kick out all the Jews (but other nations didn't want them), so they overcrowded them into slums (called "Ghettos"), and eventually later in the war built the death camps. The Nazis also planned to deport all the Russians out of Russia up to the Urals, and so on.
(not all concentration camps are illegal death camps)

@JaminGrey Yeah the Nazis had a really fucked up ideology where "the Jews" are behind everything and are the mortal enemies of the aryans where only 1 "race" could survive. So they first removed them from public and cultural life, forced them to leave the country in masses, then deported them into concentration camps (often further eastwards) and while probably all concentration camps already involved murder to some degree, they also had dedicated death camps where death by labor and/or gas was not a side effect but the intended purpose.

Interesting to bring up the emphasis on "living lawfully", because after WW2 the Czechoslovaks made mass deportations of non-Slavic populations solely based on them being non-Slavic, even though they have been living there centuries before any Czech or Slovak statehood formed. Yet it was accepted by Western powers, and it is still legally in effect to this very day, despite being in the EU.

@vsz: well, I'm not claiming people always agree what 'living lawfully' means--in particular whose laws when there are conflicting territorial claims. Just see the recent/perennial conflicts in the Middle East (or between Russia and Ukraine) for more of that.

@HagenvonEitzen My understanding is the none of the crimes prosecuted at the Nuremberg trials were ones committed against German citizens because, as you say, Germany was a sovereign state and could have whatever laws it wanted. However, when they deported people from France, Netherlands, etc. to concentration camps, German laws had no jurisdiction. Regardless of whether their actions were legal under German law, they were not legal under French law, and they were committed in France.

@Acccumulation: "none of the crimes prosecuted at the Nuremberg trials were ones committed against German citizens" That's partly wrong. They came under the purview of the first N trial but they were deemed not war crimes, because the war had not yet started. But the Allied Control Law 10 changed that for subsequent trials. Which is why suggested people take their thoughts/questions on this to H.SE.

@Acccumulation: the latter law (#10) explicitly added "whether or not in violation of the domestic laws of the country where perpetrated".

@Acccumulation There was however some variation how the various allied courts interpreted the "whether or not" business, even in the aftermath of Law #10 https://www.nationalww2museum.org/war/articles/crimes-against-humanity-international-law E.g. various courts comprised of US judges applied it differently(!) depending how conservative they were. One court let off defendants who euthanized [only] German mentally ill. But another (in the "Justice Case" sentenced defendants for murdering German Jews.

@Acccumulation: the summary of the latter includes a count (#3) that mentions "against German civilians".

As other answers have suggested, this is just a difference between US English and UK/European English.
To an American, “deportation” is no more loaded a term than “fine”, “imprisonment”, or “execution”.  It’s a just and legal punishment if you deserve it and have been duly convicted and sentenced; if not, not.
Strangely, the word “confiscation” is stigmatized.  Yes, property can be confiscated after due process of law, but the word by itself and undecorated suggests injustice.

UK English does not consider "deportation" a loaded term either.
